# How to get client IP address and UDP port in WCF?

Tags: android, ios, iphone, wcf, ipad

I developed some services in WCf which are consumed by Smart device e.g. Android etc

I am getting client (Device) endpoint (IpAddress,port) in WCF service when they are called by Device. And after that I send a UDP message on that IPAddress and port but that UDP message donot reach to destination.

May be there is some problem which extracting port from Client as service could be on HTTP and I get the port of HTTP and send UDP message on that port which that port does not accept.

please help.

below is the code to extract client IPAddress and PORT and send UDP message on that point

```
OperationContext context = OperationContext.Current;
MessageProperties messageProperties = context.IncomingMessageProperties;
var endpointProperty = messageProperties[RemoteEndpointMessageProperty.Name] as RemoteEndpointMessageProperty;
int nRemotePort = 0;
string sRemoteAddress = "";
if (endpointProperty != null)
{
     sRemoteAddress = endpointProperty.Address;
     nRemotePort = endpointProperty.Port;
}
```

// got IPAddress and Port, now send UDP message to address

```
UdpClient udpClient = new UdpClient();
udpClient.Connect(sRemoteAddress, nRemotePort);
string msgTag = ((DateTime.Now.Month.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0') + DateTime.Now.Day.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0') + DateTime.Now.Year.ToString().PadLeft(4, '0')) + DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0') + DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0')) + DateTime.Now.Second.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0') + DateTime.Now.Millisecond.ToString().PadLeft(3, '0');


string msgBody = "786022^Successfully Connected to Server, now send Data";
string msg = "8^" + msgTag + "^45^1^0^" + msgBody.Length + Convert.ToChar(2).ToString() + msgBody + Convert.ToChar(4).ToString();
byte[] sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg);
udpClient.Send(sendBytes, sendBytes.Length);
udpClient.Close();
```

Comment: UDP doesn't guarantee the data actually reaches its destination. If you need to make sure your data reaches the device, go TCP (on a different port, of course: the one you get from the request is obviously already taken). Also, if your device is on mobile network, i highly doubt it's actually directly reachable like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the mystery, Actually I was extracting TCP port from WCF service and send my UDP message on that port, which was wrong.

Now I have to stick a port for UDP in Device application and sending my messages to IPAddress extracted from WCF and that decided UDP port.